# Python pandas stopping on invalid characters

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, csv

I am reading a csv file and writing to a mongodb as json using the code below

```
bucket_name = "my-bucket"
file_name = "input.csv"
csv_data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('gs://' + bucket_name + '/' + file_name, encoding='utf-8'))
csv_data = csv_data.to_dict(orient="records")
db.task.insert_many(csv_data)
```

the below is the input csv file

```
ID,Name,Identity,Alignment,EyeColor,HairColor,Gender,Status,Appearances,FirstAppearance,Year,Universe
100001,Claude Potier (Earth-616),Secret,Neutral,Hazel,Brown,Male,Living,2,àå÷-00,2000,DC
100002,Elektra Natchios (Earth-616),Secret,Neutral,Blue,Black,Female,Living,280,éðå-81,1981,Marvel
100003,Thomas Williams (Earth-616),Secret,Neutral,Black,,Male,Living,1,àåâ-02,2002,DC
100004,Mogul (Earth-616),,,,Bald,,Living,,îàé-70,1970,DC
```

It has got some characters which are not Unicode. Is there a way so that

1. I can replace such non valid characters with something like "invalid" and continue processing and store in the mongo database.
2. Is there a way to put as it is in the database?

The error I am getting

```
File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1499, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Have you tried `encoding=` to something other than `'utf-8'`?

Comment: If your CSV is corrupt, I'm wondering if the [FiveThirtyEight Comic Characters Dataset](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/comic-characters) could be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding 'encoding_errors='ignore'':

```
csv_data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('gs://' + bucket_name + '/' + file_name, encoding='utf-8', encoding_errors='ignore'))
```

Comment: That works and the data gets stored in the mongo without the invalid characters. Is there a way that we can modify the field in the dataframe with "invalid", so that when i look in the mongo I know in the source there are some invalid characters?

Comment: For that you need to find and post the invalid characters